# Узнать тип сборки (dev,prod) env

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Приложение на create-react-app. Мне требуется менять url в запросе исходя из текущей сборки проекта. Есть я запускаю `npm run start` мне нужен url=localhost. Если `npm run build` url=site.com

Comment: Подходит ли process.env.NODE_ENV  для этого,

Answer (score 0):

Для отладки определите переменную в файле `.env.development` а для компиляции в прод `.env.production`

Это описано в документации https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables